# How to use a package in oneditprepare function in node template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am planning to make a select tag. It should show a list of files available in ftp server.

I am using basic-ftp npm package for this purpose and I am able to use it in the **.js** file but I am not sure how I have to use it in the oneditprepare function so that I can get the list of files available in the server.

My **oneditprepare** function is:

```
oneditprepare: async function () {

  example();
    ftpList = [];
    ftpListNames = [];

    async function example() {

      const ftp = require("basic-ftp");
      const client = new ftp.Client();
      client.ftp.verbose = true;
      try {
        await client.access({
          host: "192.168.104.105",
          user: "testuser",
          password: "1234",
        });
        // console.log(await client.list("/files"));
        ftpList = await client.list("/files");

        for (let i = 0; i < ftpList.length; i++) {
          ftpListNames.push(ftpList[i].name);
        }
        console.log("ftpListNames :>> ", ftpListNames);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

But using this gives me an error saying **require is not defined.**

So I made a change to my settings.js file of node-red and added the package but still could not find a solution.

Comment: Are you using es modules?

Comment: No, I'm not using es modules

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you don't

Longer answer:

You can not make FTP connections from the `oneditprepare` function because that runs in the browser. So you need to add all that code to the `.js` file and implement HTTP REST endpoints that can be from within the `oneditprepare` function to trigger it running in the Node-RED backend.

Comment: [Loading extra resources in the editor](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/resources#:~:text=With%20Node%2DRED%201.3%20or%20later%2C%20if%20a%20module%20has%20a%20directory%20called%20resources%20at%20the%20top%20level%2C%20the%20runtime%20will%20make%20anything%20in%20that%20directory%20available%20to%20the%20editor%20under%20the%20url) In these docs it says that instead of http rest endpoints we can directly include our .js files in the resources folder. So is this approach applicable for my use case of ftp call?

Comment: No, that will not work, because the web browser's sand box will not let you open anything but a http or WebSockets connection